# Issue with LWJGL Display

Tags: java, opengl, window, lwjgl

I am currently in the process of making a tile based 2D platformer using lwjgl. I have a character that is able to run and jump all around the map. I have run into a strange problem when moving the window. When I move the window the game will freeze which isn't a big deal because when you let go it unfreezes, but after it unfreezes my character will end up moving down a number of tiles based on how long you hold the window or move the window for. Is there anything i should know about the library and the display, or do you need to see the code for the window initialization or the physics and collision detection? I have no idea why the movement of the window would have anything to do with the players position!

Solution:
After quite a lot of thought and attempts to fix the problem, I had realized that i am using a delta in my update methods, because delta is calculated by the time between each update, because the game freezes when the window is "moved" or "grabbed" the delta value becomes very large in a short period of time causing the player or object to be moved a very large amount at once. To fix this i simply put a limit on the delta value that gets passed into my update methods so that the player would not be able to move 10+ tiles at a time.

Comment: That is not a good solution, it's a hack. You should probably address the issue of the screen freezing. Without posting any code, though, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: No you shouldn't limit the *delta* value in any way, though you should perform some better collision detection.

Comment: I have no idea why the display freezes when it is moved or grabbed. and no one else seems to have this problem. The limit i had put on delta is very large, the player would not be able to play because it would be so laggy!